# General solution of linear homogeneous equation given roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have a linear homogeneous equation whose characteristic equation has the following roots:

$$
\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \gamma, \gamma, \delta +i \epsilon, \delta + i \epsilon, \delta - i \epsilon, \delta - i \epsilon
$$

That's nine roots, both real and complex, some repeated, and the complex ones in conjugate pairs.

What is the general solution of this equation?

If the roots are

$$
\alpha, \beta, 0, 0, 0, \delta +i \epsilon, \delta + i \epsilon, \delta - i \epsilon, \delta - i \epsilon
$$
how does this modify the solution?

This was a serious lacuna in the maths I did for my physics degree and I'm trying to get myself back up to speed now I have a daughter who is studying this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the independent variable is $t$, the general solution can be written as
$$
c_1e^{\alpha t}+c_2e^{\beta t}+e^{\gamma t}(c_3+c_4t+c_5t^2)
+e^{\delta t}(c_6\cos(\epsilon t)+c_7\sin(\epsilon t))
+te^{\delta t}(c_8\cos(\epsilon t)+c_9\sin(\epsilon t)).
$$
If $\gamma=0$, it becomes
$$
c_1e^{\alpha t}+c_2e^{\beta t}+c_3+c_4t+c_5t^2
+e^{\delta t}(c_6\cos(\epsilon t)+c_7\sin(\epsilon t))
+te^{\delta t}(c_8\cos(\epsilon t)+c_9\sin(\epsilon t)).
$$

Comment: That's enormously helpful as a canonical example.